# My app appears as an option when selecting an app for an email Intent

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <data android:scheme="mailto" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Fragment:

```
class OptionsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener, Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener  {

    override fun onPreferenceClick(preference: Preference): Boolean {
        when (preference.key){
            "contact_developer" -> {
                Log.d("PreferenceEnabled", "contacteddeveloper")
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
                    type = "*/*"
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Enquiry")
                    data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
                }
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

When my `Preference` is clicked, it fires the email intent. However, my app appears in the options (along with other email apps).

`data = Uri.parse("mailto:")` is meant to filter the targeted apps to only emails.

Why is my app a suggested email app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is my app a suggested email app?

Because you put in the `<intent-filter>` saying that you want to respond to those `Intents`.

If that is not what you want, remove:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Ok it works now, thanks. However, I thought that `<intent-filter>` gives my app permission to launch an email intent?

Comment: @Zorgan: No. There is no permission required to launch that `ACTION_SENDTO` `Intent`. The `<intent-filter>` advertises that you want to *receive* such an `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the `<intent-filter>` my email intent did not open. I realized that I needed to add `queries` to the `manifest.xml` file, outside of the `<activity/>` tags. Here is the code:

```
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
    <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
  </intent>
</queries>
```